# Why is multidimensional Reverse slow?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, bugs, function-comparison

**Bug introduced in 6.0 and persisting through 14.0.**

---

I have found that multidimensional `Reverse` is ~10 times slower than exact `-1 ;; 1 ;; -1`:

```
n = 1000;
mat = RandomReal[1, {n, n}];

mat2 = Reverse[mat, 2]; // AbsoluteTiming
mat3 = mat[[All, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.088234, Null} *)
(* {0.006836, Null} *)

mat2 == mat3
(* True *)
```

Why? Is it a bug?

Both produced arrays are packed.

I use *Mathematica* 9.0.1 on Linux. *Mathematica* 8 has the same problem.

---

Reply from the Wolfram Technical Support:

> Thank you for your message.
>
> I could reproduce this performance issue on Mathematica 9.
>
> I have filed a report on this to our database and thank you for bringing this issue to our attention.

*Wolfram Technical Support* case identification : **[CASE:424077]**

Comment: Neither of them seem to unpack the array.  Maybe this is something that should be reported to support.

Comment: Results are the opposite for SparseArray objects

Answer (score 11):

*Mathematica* is full of these idiosyncrasies and honestly I have no idea how one is to figure out why.  Still I think it's an interesting question.  One possibility is that `Part` was optimized at some point and `Reverse` got left behind.  In my experience `Part` is highly optimized for packed arrays.  At least in v7 `Reverse` is faster on unpacked data:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]

timeAvg[func_] :=
  Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

mat = Developer`FromPackedArray @ mat;

Reverse[mat, 2];           // timeAvg
mat[[All, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1]]; // timeAvg
```

> ```
> 0.005872
>
> 0.009736
> ```

Comment: In 10.3 the difference is quite small (2%), but it exits.

Comment: The difference is small only for *unpacked* arrays as in your answer. For packed arrays `Reverse` is still 10 times slower.