# How to reflect the entries of a square matrix about its anti-diagonal?

Tags: matrix

I need help with writing the mathematica code to reflect the entries of a square matrix about its anti-diagonal. I know to do it about the main diagonal using `Transpose`.

What should be the precise code?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `Transpose@Reverse[m, {1, 2}]`.

Comment: `Transpose@m[[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1]]` is faster for big numerical arrays because of the [perforamce bug in `Reverse`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37777)

Answer (score 5):

```
mA = Array[a, {4, 4}]
```

> {{a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[1, 4]},
>  {a[2, 1], a[2, 2], a[2, 3],
>     a[2, 4]}, 
> {a[3, 1], a[3, 2], a[3, 3], a[3, 4]},
>  {a[4, 1], a[4, 2], 
>     a[4, 3], a[4, 4]}}

```
mB = Reverse /@ (Transpose[Reverse /@ mA])
```

> {{a[4, 4], a[3, 4], a[2, 4], a[1, 4]}, 
> {a[4, 3], a[3, 3], a[2,
>   3],    a[1, 3]},
>  {a[4, 2], a[3, 2], a[2, 2], a[1, 2]},
>  {a[4,
>   1], a[3, 1],    a[2, 1], a[1, 1]}}

Answer (score 1):

```
rF = With[{m = #, dim = Length@#}, Array[m[[dim + 1 - #2, dim + 1 - #1]] &, {dim, dim}]] &;

mA = Array[a, {4, 4}];
Row[MatrixForm /@ {mA, rF@mA}]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a[1,1] & a[1,2] & a[1,3] & a[1,4] \\
 a[2,1] & a[2,2] & a[2,3) & a[2,4] \\
 a[3,1] & a[3,2] & a[3,3) & a[3,4] \\
 a[4,1] & a[4,2] & a[4,3) & a[4,4] \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a[4,4]& a[3,4]& a[2,4]& a[1,4]\\
 a[4,3]& a[3,3]& a[2,3]& a[1,3]\\
 a[4,2]& a[3,2]& a[2,2]& a[1,2]\\
 a[4,1]& a[3,1]& a[2,1]& a[1,1]\\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
aA = RandomInteger[9, {5, 5}];
Row[MatrixForm /@ {aA, rF@aA}]
```

$ \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 3 & 6 & 4 & 0 & 9 \\
 5 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
 3 & 7 & 4 & 8 & 2 \\
 1 & 9 & 7 & 7 & 2 \\
 0 & 4 & 1 & 8 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 9 \\
 8 & 7 & 8 & 4 & 0 \\
 1 & 7 & 4 & 3 & 4 \\
 4 & 9 & 7 & 3 & 6 \\
 0 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right) $