# How can I select four points on a sphere to make a regular tetrahedron so that its coordinates are integer numbers?

Tags: diophantine-equations

I want to select four points lie on the sphere `(x-1)^2 + (y-3)^2 + (z-5)^2 = (5* Sqrt[3])^2` so that its coordinates are integer numbers to make a regular tetrahedron. I tried

```
ClearAll[a, b, r, c];
a = 1;
b = 3;
c = 5;
r = 5* Sqrt[3]; ss = 
 Subsets[{x, y, z} /. 
   Solve[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 == r^2}, {x, y, z}, 
    Integers], {4}];
list = Select[
  ss, ( EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] ==  
      EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[3]]] == 
      EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[4]]] == 
      EuclideanDistance[#[[2]], #[[4]]] == 
      EuclideanDistance[#[[2]], #[[3]]] == 
      EuclideanDistance[#[[3]], #[[4]]] && 
     Det[{#[[1]] - #[[2]], #[[1]] - #[[3]], #[[1]] - #[[4]]}] != 
      0 &) ]
```

About ten minutes, I can not get the result? How can I get the result?

Comment: It appears that you are trying to find a *regular* tetrahedron. In general, a tetrahedron doesn’t have edges of equal length, so you have probably found *many* tetrahedra with integral vertices on that sphere.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- No such regular tetrahedron,even no triangle of such regular tetrahedron.
- If there are exist such regular tetrahedron, the length of its side should be `r/(Sqrt[3/2]/2)`. We found many lines satisfies this condition, but no triangle,so there are no regular tetrahedron.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
{a,b,c}={1,3,5};
r = 15;
pairs = Subsets[{x, y, z} /. 
    Solve[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 == r^2}, {x, y, z}, 
     Integers], {2}];
test2[{p1_, p2_}] := (p1 - p2) . (p1 - p2) == (r/(Sqrt[3/2]/2))^2;
lines = Pick[pairs, test2 /@ pairs];
Graphics3D[Line[lines]]
```

[image]

```
{a,b,c}={1,3,5};
r = 15;
triples = 
  Subsets[{x, y, z} /. 
    Solve[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 == r^2}, {x, y, z}, 
     Integers], {3}];
test3[{p1_, p2_, 
    p3_}] := (p1 - p2) . (p1 - p2) == (p2 - p3) . (p2 - p3) == (p3 - 
      p1) . (p3 - p1) == (r/(Sqrt[3/2]/2))^2;
triangles = Pick[triples, test3 /@ triples]
```

> `{}`

### Edit : Graph theory method

For `r = 33*Sqrt[3];`, there are `26*5=130` subgraphs means that there are `26*5=130` tetrahedron in the original question.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
{a, b, c} = {1, 3, 5};
r = 33*Sqrt[3];
length = r/(Sqrt[3/2]/2);
pts = SolveValues[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 == r^2}, {x, y, 
    z}, Integers];
adjmatrix = 
  SparseArray[{i_, 
      j_} /; (pts[[i]] - pts[[j]]) . (pts[[i]] - pts[[j]]) == 
      length^2 -> 1, {Length@pts, Length@pts}];
adjgraph = AdjacencyGraph[adjmatrix];
subgraphs = FindIsomorphicSubgraph[adjgraph, CompleteGraph[4], All];
tetrahedrons = pts[[VertexList[#]]] & /@ subgraphs;
Graphics3D[ConvexHullRegion /@ tetrahedrons, Boxed -> False]
```

```
adjgraph
```

[image]

[image]

### Edit

- Now we do not assume that we know in advance that the tetrahedron has sides of length `r/(Sqrt[3/2]/2)`.

```
{a, b, c} = {1, 3, 5};
r = 33 Sqrt[3];
pts = {x, y, z} /. 
   Solve[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 == r^2}, {x, y, z}, 
    Integers];
pairs = Table[
   If[i > j, {i, j} -> (pts[[i]] - pts[[j]]) . (pts[[i]] - pts[[j]]), 
    Nothing], {i, Length@pts}, {j, Length@pts}];
groups = GatherBy[Flatten[pairs, 1], Last];
graphs = Graph[pts, #, VertexCoordinates -> pts] & /@ Keys@groups;
subgraphs = 
 FindIsomorphicSubgraph[#, CompleteGraph[4], All] & /@ graphs /. {} ->
     Nothing // First
```

```
Graph[VertexList@#, EdgeList@#, VertexCoordinates -> VertexList@#, 
   EdgeStyle -> RandomColor[]] & /@ subgraphs
```

Comment: It is interresting if we draw one regular tetrahedron by using [this method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/289030/how-to-draw-a-square-with-all-vertices-lie-on-a-sphere)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better instead to show the `AbsoluteTiming` of the whole function? not just the line`tetrahedrons = pts[[VertexList[#]]] & /@ subgraphs; // AbsoluteTiming`?

Comment: `FindIsomorphicSubgraph` is a correct, but not a necessary method here. The graph contains at most 4-cliques, and thus more efficient `FindClique` can be used in this case.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**: Improved distance computation efficiency *a lot* by using `DistanceMatrix`:

```
With[{r = 33 Sqrt[3]},
  With[
   (* Find integer-valued points on the sphere. *)
   {pts = {x, y, z} /. 
      Solve[Element[{x, y, z}, Sphere[{1, 3, 5}, r]], Integers]},
   (* Compute distance matrix for the points. *)
   DistanceMatrix[pts, DistanceFunction -> SquaredEuclideanDistance] //
    (* Find indices of edges which may be a part of a regular
       tetrahedron in this circumsphere by length. *)
    Position[(8/3) r^2] //
    (* Construct graph edges with coordinates as vertices. *)
    Map[UndirectedEdge @@ pts[[#]] &]]] //
 (* Find all 4-cliques. *)
 FindClique[Graph[#], {4}, All] &
```

$r = 33\sqrt{3}$ evaluates now in 24 *milli*seconds on average on my laptop.

It should be noted that `FindClique` returns maximal cliques. For exact 4-clique subgraphs one should normally use
`FindIsomorphicSubgraph` but that is not necessary here since these graphs don't have larger than 4-cliques as one can have only four points at equal distances from each other in the three-dimensional Euclidean space.

---

**EDIT**: Converted the search into a graph clique problem:

```
With[{r = 33 Sqrt[3]},
 Select[
     Subsets[
      (* Find integer-valued points on the sphere. *)
      {x, y, z} /.
       Solve[Element[{x, y, z}, Sphere[{1, 3, 5}, r]], Integers], {2}],
     (* Select edges which may be a part of a regular tetrahedron in
        this circumsphere by length. *)
     SquaredEuclideanDistance @@ # == (8/3) r^2 &] //
    (* Construct a graph and find all 4-cliques. *)
    MapApply@UndirectedEdge // FindClique[#, {4}, All] &]
```

This is not the fastest solution but it's quite concise, and for $r = 33\sqrt{3}$ evaluates in 0.56 seconds on my laptop.

---

**EDIT**: A new, much more scalable approach here, the original solution under it.

```
With[{r = 33 Sqrt[3]},
   Select[
    Subsets[
     (* Find integer-valued points on the sphere. *)
     {x, y, z} /.
      Solve[Element[{x, y, z}, Sphere[{1, 3, 5}, r]], 
       Integers], {2}],
    (* Select edges which may be a part of a regular tetrahedron in
       this circumsphere by length. *)
    SquaredEuclideanDistance @@ # == Evaluate[(8/3) r^2] &]] //
  Select[
    (* Select from pairs of such edges so that *)
    Flatten[#, 1] & /@ Subsets[#, {2}],
    (* resulting vertices form a regular tetrahedron. *)
    Equal @@ (SquaredEuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[#, {2}]) &] & //
 (* Delete redundant reorderings. *)
 DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]
```

... this computes 130 solutions for $r = 33\sqrt{3}$ in less than 10 seconds on my laptop while my old code below requires almost four minutes to do it.

Solution for $r = 99\sqrt{3}$ below.

[image]

---

**Old answer**:

Brute-force search with a small tweak (find valid equilateral triangles first) is probably the most efficient solution when the sphere radius is 15 (original question):

```
With[
  {(* Integer-valued points on the sphere. *)
   onsphere =
    {x, y, z} /.
     Solve[Element[{x, y, z}, Sphere[{1, 3, 5}, 15]], Integers],
   (* Function which returns True if all points in the list
      are pairwise equidistant. *)
   eqdist = Equal @@ (SquaredEuclideanDistance @@@ Subsets[#, {2}]) &},
  Table[
   (* Return valid tetrahedra. *)
   If[eqdist[Append[i, j]],
    Append[i, j],
    Nothing],
   (* Equilateral triangles on the sphere. *)
   {i, Select[Subsets[onsphere, {3}], eqdist]},
   (* All individual points to test along with the triangles. *)
   {j, onsphere}]] //
  (* Delete redundant reorderings. *)
  Flatten[#, 1] & // DeleteDuplicatesBy[Sort]

(* {} *)
```

Result is empty which means there are no such solutions.

With sphere radius of $5\sqrt{3}$ 14 solutions are found in 0.6 seconds, matching @cvgmt's result.

Comment: (+1) Faster. And there are essential 14 different tetrahedrons in the `list`.  `{GatherBy[list, Map@*Sort] // Length, 
 Gather[list, 
   RegionEqual[ConvexHullRegion[#1], ConvexHullRegion[#2]] &] // 
  Length}`

Comment: @kirma Your code  need DeleteCases when I try `Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 9 Sqrt[3]]`. The result must be smaller. There are 34 tetrahedrons.

Comment: @cvgmt Added a duplicate-removal step in the end.

Comment: Very clean and very fast, impressive!

Answer (score 6):

I used `PowersRepresentations` as  Daniel Lichtblau did [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289000/72953) as it felt natural to me when I first saw this type of problem.

With **Version 3**, I get the 130 solutions for $r=33~\sqrt{3}$ in less than 0.5 seconds on my laptop:

## Version 3

---

Noticing that the `distances` matrix in **Version 2** was symmetrical, I roughly cut my time in half. I used Stelio's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69236/72953) to create the `distances` matrix entries below the diagonal when I needed to index on it.

**r =33 Sqrt[3], using symmetry of distance matrix**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
AbsoluteTiming[center = {1, 3, 5};
 r = 33 Sqrt[3];
 (*get positive integer coordinates on r=15 sphere*)
 nnvals = PowersRepresentations[r^2, 3, 2];
 permVals = Flatten[Permutations /@ nnvals, 1];
 
 (*multiply the coords by all possible signs*)
 signs = Tuples[{-1, 1}, {3}];
 alltriples = Union[Flatten[Outer[Times, signs, permVals, 1], 1]];
 
 (*shift to center of sphere*)
 alltriples = # + center & /@ alltriples;
 
 (*side length from cvgmt's answer*)
 sideLength = r/(Sqrt[3/2]/2);
 
 (*note because of the +/- and permutations, lTrips is always even*)
 lTrips = Length@alltriples;
 (*take only the first half of alltriples, since the distance matrix \
is symmetrical*)
 upper = Take[alltriples, lTrips/2];
 (*calculate distances for first half of list to all of list*)
 distances = Outer[EuclideanDistance, upper, alltriples, 1];
 
 (*get list of coords that are sideLength away from each coord*)
 verticesWithoutSelf = (Flatten@Position[#, sideLength]) & /@ 
   distances;
 (*add the coord itself to its own list*)
 vertices = MapIndexed[Sort@Join[#2, #1] &, verticesWithoutSelf];
 
 (*get tetrahedron candidates,sort,and delete duplicates*)
 verts4 = Flatten[Sort@Subsets[#, {4}] & /@ vertices, 1];
 verts4 = DeleteDuplicates[verts4];
 
 (*create part of distance matrix below diagonal so we can index on \
it*)
 lowerDistances = 
  Reverse /@ (Transpose[Reverse /@ distances]) // Transpose;
 fullDistances = Join[distances, lowerDistances];
 
 (*grab indices from full distance matrix fullDistances*)
 distFun[v1_, v2_] := fullDistances[[v1, v2]];
 (*get distances between each vertex of the tetrahedron candidates*)
 edges = Outer[distFun[#1, #2] &, #, #, 1] & /@ verts4;
 (*get unique edge lengths*)
 edges = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[#]]] & /@ edges;
 (*a regular tetrahedron will only have lengths sideLength and 0 \
(length to self)*)
 allSameSideLength = Flatten@Position[edges, {0, sideLength}];
 (*get tetrahedron vertex coordinates*)
 tetraVerts = verts4[[allSameSideLength]];
 tetrahedrons = Part[alltriples, #] & /@ tetraVerts;
]

(*{0.427283, Null}*)
```

**r = 5 Sqrt[3]**

```
(*same Version 3 code, just different r*)

(*{0.007682, Null}*)
```

As a small note, you don't actually have shift `alltriples` to the `center` of the sphere, you could apply this shift later to `tetrahedrons` and get the same thing since integer-integer = integer. This doesn't seem to make any difference in computation time however.

---

## Version 2

An improvement on  **Version 1**, added some comments

**r= 33 Sqrt[3]**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
AbsoluteTiming[
 center = {1, 3, 5};
 r = 33 Sqrt[3];
 (*get positive integer coordinates on r=15 sphere*)
 nnvals = PowersRepresentations[r^2, 3, 2];
 permVals = Flatten[Permutations /@ nnvals, 1];
 
 (*multiply the coords by all possible signs*)
 signs = Tuples[{-1, 1}, {3}];
 alltriples = Union[Flatten[Outer[Times, signs, permVals, 1], 1]];
 
 (*shift to center of sphere*)
 alltriples = # + center & /@ alltriples;
 
 (*side length from cvgmt's answer*)
 sideLength = r/(Sqrt[3/2]/2);
 
 (*calculate distance between all coords on the sphere*)
 distances = Outer[EuclideanDistance, alltriples, alltriples, 1];
 
 (*get list of coords that are sideLength away from each coord*)
 verticesWithoutSelf = (Flatten@Position[#, sideLength]) & /@ 
   distances;
 (*add the coord itself to its own list*)
 vertices = MapIndexed[Sort@Join[#2, #1] &, verticesWithoutSelf];
 
 (*get tetrahedron candidates, sort, and delete duplicates*)
 verts4 = Flatten[Sort@Subsets[#, {4}] & /@ vertices, 1];
 verts4 = DeleteDuplicates[verts4];
 
 (*I just made this function to get distances[[v1,v2]]*)
 distFun[v1_, v2_] := distances[[v1, v2]];
 (*get distances between each vertex of the tetrahedron candidates*)
 edges = Outer[distFun[#1, #2] &, #, #, 1] & /@ verts4;
 (*get unique edge lengths*)
 edges = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[#]]] & /@ edges;
 
 (*a regular tetrahedron will only have lengths sideLength and 0 \
(length to self)*)
 allSameSideLength = Flatten@Position[edges, {0, sideLength}];
 (*get tetrahedron vertex coordinates*)
 tetraVerts = verts4[[allSameSideLength]];
 tetrahedrons = Part[alltriples, #] & /@ tetraVerts;]
Graphics3D[ConvexHullRegion /@ tetrahedrons]

(*{0.805232, Null}*)
```

For anyone wanting to further optimize for speed, the bottleneck is calculating the distances between all the integer coordinates:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 distances = Outer[EuclideanDistance, alltriples, alltriples, 1];]
(*{0.762782, Null}*)
```

Also, the `AbsoluteTiming` of `distances` looks like it should be proportional to `Length[alltriples]^2`. Part of `alltriples` definition is a `Permutation`...this is probably not possible but, if we calculated the distances for one permutation of coordinates, could we draw conclusions about other permutations?

**r = 5 Sqrt[3]**

```
(*Same Version 2 code, just different r*)

(*{0.013104, Null}*)
```

---

## Version 1

**r = 33 Sqrt[3]**

```
 Clear["Global`*"];
AbsoluteTiming[

 center = {1, 3, 5};
 r = 33 Sqrt[3];
 nnvals = PowersRepresentations[r^2, 3, 2];
 permVals = Flatten[Permutations /@ nnvals, 1];
 signs = Tuples[{-1, 1}, {3}];
 alltriples = Union[Flatten[Outer[Times, signs, permVals, 1], 1]];
 alltriples = # + center & /@ alltriples;
 
 sideLength = r/(Sqrt[3/2]/2);
 
 distances = Outer[EuclideanDistance, alltriples, alltriples, 1];
 
 tetras = Flatten[Table[
    candidateVertices = 
     Join[{i}, 
      Flatten[Position[distances[[i]], n_ /; n == sideLength]]];
    indices = Subsets[candidateVertices, {4}];
    Part[alltriples, #] & /@ indices
    , {i, distances // Length}], 1];
 sortedTetras = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ tetras];
 allSameSidePositions = 
  Flatten[Position[
    Table[Tally[
       DeleteCases[Flatten[Outer[EuclideanDistance, i, i, 1]], 
        0]][[All, 1]], {i, sortedTetras}], n_ /; n == {sideLength}]];
 tetrahedrons = sortedTetras[[allSameSidePositions]];
 ]
Graphics3D[ConvexHullRegion /@ tetrahedrons]
(*{2.0544, Null}*)
```

[image]

**r = 5 Sqrt[3]**

```
(*same old code as Version 1, just different r*)

(*{0.028064, Null}*)
```

[image]

---

Comment: (+1) fastest. But the reason for the fast is not because of the use of PowersRepresentations.

Comment: @cvgmt Can you repair your code to become faster?

Comment: @cvgmt I added comments and further optimized my answer if you would like to play with it.

Comment: @ydd Thank you for your edits. You can add an answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288956/how-can-i-get-all-squares-on-this-sphere-so-that-its-coordinates-are-integer-num)

Comment: @cvgmt I think I beat it by using `DistanceMatrix` and `FindClique`...