# Reverse element in nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list as the following:

```
list={{1,9},{7,0},{8,6}....}
```

How can I reverse the element in such way that the output would be the following:

```
{{9,1},{0,7},{6,8}....}
```

I tried `Map[Reverse,{list}]` but it didn't work.

Comment: Either `list[[All, {2,1}]]`, or more generally `list[[All, Reverse[Range[Length[First[list]]]]]]`

Comment: Take away the `{}`'s: `Map[Reverse, list]` or `Reverse /@ map`.

Comment: Closely related [Why is multidimensional Reverse slow?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37777/why-is-multidimensional-reverse-slow)

Answer (score 10):

`Reverse` takes a level specification so:

```
Reverse[list, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a simple pattern match and replacement rule, such as:

```
list = {{1, 9}, {7, 0}, {8, 6}};
list /. {a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ} :> {b, a}
(*  {{9, 1}, {0, 7}, {6, 8}}. *)
```

For this specific example, you could drop the ?NumberQs from the pattern to be matched.  But, without them, the approach would not produce the intended outcome if the length of the outer list were 2.  For that case, the outcome would be as follows:

```
{{1, 9}, {7, 0}} /. {a_, b_} :> {b, a}
(*. {{7, 0}, {1, 9}}. *)
```