# Using Do loop to swap each element in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I am currently studying the functional programming part of Mathematica. But I am very confused right now about what I have learned so far.

This because I saw an example in textbook using `Do` loop to swap list elements.

For example, original list :

```
lis = {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}}
```

**Desired Result should be**:

> ```
> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}}
> ```

I try to write the program code as below, but no error, no result in the end.

```
 lis = {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}};

 Do[temp[i] = {lis[[i, 2]], lis[[i, 1]]}, {i, 1, Length[lis]}];

 temp
```

For fixing this issue, I tried to rewirte line two as:

```
 Do[temp[[i]] = {lis[[i, 2]], lis[[i, 1]]}, {i, 1, Length[lis]}];
```

But got errors as below which I also don't know why:

> Set::noval: Symbol temp in part assignment does not have an immediate value.
>
> General::stop: Further output of Set::write will be suppressed during this calculation.

So really appreciate anyone could clarify such problem. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Why not `Map[Reverse, lis]` ?

Comment: because I follow the example from the textbook, so I got some further questions about this example.

Comment: you would need to "initialize" `temp` as a list to use this approach, eg put `temp = {0, 0, 0}` or `temp=ConstantArray[0,Length@lis]` before the `Do` loop.

Comment: I would not call this method 'functional'. See: [Reverse element in nested list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105601/5478)

Answer (score 3):

Two small errors in your code...

```
 lis = {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}};

 Do[temp[i] = {lis[[i, 2]], lis[[i, 1]]}, {i, 1, Length[lis]}];

 temp
```

You need to initialize `temp` to the right size, and then it should be `temp[[i]]` not `temp[i]`.

```
temp = lis = {{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, 3}};

Do[temp[[i]] = {lis[[i, 2]], lis[[i, 1]]}, {i, 1, Length[lis]}];

temp

(*    {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}}    *)
```

I am guessing that this is the "before" example in your functional programming text?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I can understand the initialize process now. But why not temp[i] is still a confusion

Comment: The only one which answers the question so far :)

Comment: cj, think of `temp[i]` as a call of the function `temp[ ]` with argument `i`, as opposed to `temp[[i]]` which referencing the ith element of a list `temp`. Your error that you didn't understand came about because `temp` needed to be initialized.  @Kuba, sometimes folks are too clever by half. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Table[{lis[[i, 2]], lis[[i, 1]]}, {i, 1, Length@lis}]
```

> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}}

Or - a little bit more advanced

```
Map[Reverse, lis]
```

> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}}

If you want to do this with `Do`:

```
rev = {};
Do[AppendTo[rev, {lis[[i, 2]], lis[[i, 1 ]]}], {i, 1, Length@lis}];

rev
```

> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}}

The latter becomes rather slow with large lists.

Comment: Surely, if you were use `Table`, it would be `Table[Reverse @ i, {i, lis}]` and not the monster you show above.

Answer (score 1):

Just some other ways:

```
{#2, #1} & @@@ lis
```

or

```
Transpose@*Reverse@*Transpose@lis
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Reverse[{{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}},2]

Try: Do[AppendTo[newlis, Reverse[lis[[i]]]], {i, 1, 3}]
 newlis starts as an empty list,newlis={}
```

Comment: Please, review your code, add any clarification notes, etc.